# Swift XCTest load file

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, swift

I'm getting confused and haven't been able to find any answers out there.

I have a TestClass in my Test Target.  I put a file called `test.csv` into this target and on disk its stored in the same directory as all the other files.

What 3 lines of code do i need to load the file?

`let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()`

gives me this directory: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents` and there doesn't seem to be anything in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh i figured it out:

`NSBundle(forClass: <CLASSNAME>.self).URLForResource("Filename", withExtension: "extension")`

Alternatively, returning the path as String:

`NSBundle(forClass: <CLASSNAME>.self).pathForResource("Filename", ofType: "extension")`